# [graph]: build a graph of relationship

Tags: graph

According to the books I read, they often build a graph using vertices whose value ranges from 1 to n, so every vertex has a unique name.

What if I have to build a graph using vertices whose value are strings, say

```
V = {'Arm', 'Bob', 'Lin', 'Kok'}   #vertices
E = {('Arm', 'Lin'), (Bob, 'Lin'), ('Bob', 'Kok')}   #edges
```

Am I supposed to map these string vertices to integers before I build the graph for them?
Any example I can refer to?

Comment: I don't see any reason to map them to numbers. I'm not sure what software you're using, but if you're drawing with pygraphviz you can use names just fine.

Comment: @Owen, actually I'm trying to implement some graph algorithms such as DFS and BFS, the way I learned from books is to mark every discovered vertex gray or black, and every vertex is assigned a number from 1 to n, so their color can just be represented by an array color[i], but if the vertex is string, how can I do the coloring work? so I thought I should map every string vertex into a number i which ranges from 1 to n. Am I right?

Comment: You could do that. You could also store the colors in the nodes themselves (make them objects), or hold the colors in a dict and use `color[name]` to get the color.

Comment: @Owen, thanks for your suggestion, but if I want to implement it using C not python, Am I supposed to maintain a hash-table or something to store the string -> number mapping?

Comment: Well, you could, but it's probably easier making them numbers in that case ;) Sorry I assumed you were using Python because your code looks Pythonesque.

Comment: @Owen, haha, I indeed use Python, but I also want to figure out how to implement it in C. So, Owen, if it is you to deal with this problem in C, how would you do it? Will you map string into number?

Comment: Personally, I'd make them numbers, unless I had a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @Owen, Hmmm, any other way besides mapping strings into numbers?

Comment: You could make a `struct node { int color; }`, so it would be stored in the node itself. You could as you suggest use a hashtable mapping. That's all I can think of right now. You could post another question and see what other people think.

Comment: @Owen, thank you very much, it's very kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and guess you're drawing with [pygraphviz](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/)

Using strings instead of numbers, the [simple.py](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/browser/pygraphviz/trunk//examples/simple.py) example would look like:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv

A=pgv.AGraph()

A.add_edge('foo', 'bar')
A.add_edge('bar', 'baz')
A.add_edge('baz', 'foo')

A.write('simple.dot')

B=pgv.AGraph('simple.dot')
B.layout()
B.draw('simple.png')
```

Or, if you're not drawing, just building, the code you posted is a great way to represent a graph; no need to use numbers when strings work just fine.